# Python dateutil rrule error

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, python-datetime, python-dateutil

I get the following error in the example code below. I'm not sure why or what is causing the error as this code was working fine in the past. I am using Python 2.7

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'allocate_lock'
```

Here is a minimal example that contains the problem.

```
import pandas as pd
import pytz

from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from dateutil import rrule

start = pd.Timestamp('1900-01-01', tz='UTC')
end_base = pd.Timestamp('today', tz='UTC')
end = end_base + timedelta(days=365)

def canonicalize_datetime(dt):
    return datetime(dt.year, dt.month, dt.day, tzinfo=pytz.utc)

def get_rules(start, end):
    rules = []

    start = canonicalize_datetime(start)
    end = canonicalize_datetime(end)

    weekends = rrule.rrule(
        rrule.YEARLY,
        byweekday=(rrule.SA, rrule.SU),
        cache=True,
        dtstart=start,
        until=end
    )
    rules.append(weekends)

    return rules

rules = get_rules(start, end)
```

The full traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mac/Documents/test.py", line 48, in <module>
    rules = get_rules(start, end)
  File "/Users/mac/Documents/test.py", line 42, in get_rules
    until=end
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dateutil/rrule.py", line 239, in __init__
    super(rrule, self).__init__(cache)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dateutil/rrule.py", line 90, in __init__
    self._cache_lock = _thread.allocate_lock()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'allocate_lock'
```

From the dateutil source code and from user @PatrickCollins , the problem can be produced with

```
import _thread

_thread.allocate_lock()
```

Comment: How did you install `dateutil`? It looks like you might have the py3k version, somehow. Have you changed anything since the last time it worked?

Comment: @PatrickCollins I used `pip-2.7`,  I ran `pip-2.7 install --upgrade python-dateutil` just to be sure and it says everything is up to date, I just tried `python-3.4` and 3.4 is running fine.

Comment: Hm, I'm wrong about the py3k version. That's really puzzling. Can you try `import thread`, `thread.allocate_lock()` in a 2.7 shell and see what happens?

Comment: @PatrickCollins I just tried your suggestion with threads on 2.7 and had no errors.

Comment: Looking in [their source](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~dateutil/dateutil/trunk/view/head:/dateutil/rrule.py), for 2.7 compatibility they have the line `import thread as _thread`. And [`thread` definitely has an `allocate_lock` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/thread.html).

Comment: Is this the full code? Is there anything anywhere else that could be shadowing their `_thread`? Any `from foo import *`? Could you take a look in your /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dateutil/rrule.py file and make sure it has the `try: ... except ImportError: ...` block at the top?

Comment: And what does `dateutil.__version__` give you? Installing it with `pip2` and trying the same thing on my machine works fine. Really odd.

Comment: From the same directory as this script, try running `python -c 'import thread; print(thread.__file__)'` to see if you have some other module named "thread". It should throw an error, but just maybe...

Comment: @PatrickCollins 2.2 and it looks like the `_thread` from the source is causing the problem

Comment: @pyCthon Does it not contain the line `try: ... except ImportError: import thread as _thread`? That shouldn't cause any problem.

Comment: @pyCthon Oh, @AndrewJohnson has a good point -- is there a file named `thread.py` in your current directory? Or anywhere else in your path?

Comment: @PatrickCollins the directory i'm running in has one file named test.py, i'll check the path,

Comment: @AndrewJohnson that has thrown an error, `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__file__'`

Comment: @PatrickCollins here is every thread.py on my computer, 

`$ find / -name thread.py 2>/dev/null
/Applications/LibreOffice.app/Contents/MacOS/LibreOfficePython.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/concurrent/futures/thread.py
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zmq/auth/thread.py
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/concurrent/futures/thread.py`

Comment: @PatrickCollins could this be the incorrect version of dateutil? On the maintainers website it says

python-dateutil-2.0.tar.gz (Python >= 3.0)
'python-dateutil-1.5.tar.gz (Python < 3.0)' I will try with dateutil 1.5

Comment: @pyCthon 2.2 worked fine on my 2.7 install. It looks like something [not in a directory with an `__init__.py` is shadowing your `thread` module](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12540257). Also, I think there should be a `thread.py` for 2.7 in your `find` (though I can't find the 2.7 source to confirm right now) -- try rerunning it with `sudo` to see if it's somewhere inaccessible. Or, better yet, `locate`.

Comment: @pyCthon What'd be good is if you move the answer that worked for you, out from your question, post it as an answer, then mark it accepted. That way, the community can see this question is effectively solved :)

Comment: @PatrickCollins Are you on OSX? I reran this with sudo/locate and the same files came up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further investigation the problem looks to be with `pip` installing the incorrect version. The problem is resolved with installing datetuil-1.5.

`python-dateutil-2.0.tar.gz (Python >= 3.0)`

`python-dateutil-1.5.tar.gz (Python < 3.0)`

However this may lead to more questions as to why dateutil version 2.2 is working for others with python 2.7

Answer (score 1):

Got this error while running Caffe using Anaconda Python; The statements in the comments solved it for me

```
pip install --upgrade python-dateutil
Collecting python-dateutil
  Downloading python_dateutil-2.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (194kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 194kB 484kB/s 
Requirement already up-to-date: six>=1.5 in /home/alex/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from python-dateutil)
Installing collected packages: python-dateutil
  Found existing installation: python-dateutil 1.5
    Uninstalling python-dateutil-1.5:
      Successfully uninstalled python-dateutil-1.5
Successfully installed python-dateutil-2.6.0
```