# API Test Case - 'module' object has no attribute

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

```
$ python manage.py test homepage.shortlistedlist
```

When i run above django rest framework testcase file, i met below error, kindly help me to solve this problem,

```
(py3.4)testuser@testuser-To:~/projects/testfile/testfile$ python manage.py test homepage.compareproperties --settings=testfile.settings.test
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/testuser/envs/testfile/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/testuser/envs/testfile/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/testuser/envs/testfile/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 50, in run_from_argv
    super(Command, self).run_from_argv(argv)
  File "/home/testuser/envs/testfile/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/home/testuser/envs/testfile/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 71, in execute
    super(Command, self).execute(*args, **options)
  File "/home/testuser/envs/testfile/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 338, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/testuser/envs/testfile/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 88, in handle
    failures = test_runner.run_tests(test_labels)
  File "/home/testuser/envs/testfile/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 146, in run_tests
    suite = self.build_suite(test_labels, extra_tests)
  File "/home/testuser/envs/testfile/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 95, in build_suite
    tests = self.test_loader.discover(start_dir=label, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/unittest/loader.py", line 255, in discover
    self._get_directory_containing_module(top_part)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/unittest/loader.py", line 269, in _get_directory_containing_module
    full_path = os.path.abspath(module.__file__)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__file__'
```

Thanks In Advance,

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django: 'Module' object has no attribute '\_\_file\_\_'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12540257/django-module-object-has-no-attribute-file)

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve this by adding an empty `__init__.py` to the root of my project.

I think the clue is the `get_directory_containing_module()` call - without `__init__.py`, it doesn't see the directory as a module.